# Can one get a notable question silver badge for a question with more than 10 downvotes and with 3k views?

Tags: support, badges

I am interested in knowing if anyone can get [Notable Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question) silver badge for a question with more than 10 downvotes with 3k views?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are asking this?

Comment: @ Sha Wiz Dow Ard Badjes are giving for some good reason. If So it is not a good thing. i asked this question when i saw this post                                                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773242/what-is-stack-overflow-in-java

Comment: That question is now deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The views badges have absolutely nothing to do with the question's score. Notable Question is for 2,500 views, that's it. Nothing else influences it.